# Performance penalty with 1000s of running Timer objects?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Is there any performance considerations to having thousands of running Timer objects (spawned behind the scenes by calls to Reactive RX's Observable.Interval extension method)?  This would be for a server application.  The number of potentially concurrently running timers would be thousands to tens of thousands.

Comment: Even if none of the 1000 timers do anything and just sit there and tick on a regular interval, it's pretty inefficient in my opinion. I don't know what your design is, but I'm pretty sure there's a better way to implement it without using 10,000 timers.

Comment: I want to create a generic autosave object and each object would be saved at an interval.  Much cleaner design, but if there is a perf impact...

Comment: Consider programming it as if you have 1000s of timers, but implement a custom Scheduler that actually uses one, and processes logical timers as suggested by the answers.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forum response notwithstanding, the answer is about as non-trivial as it gets!!!

I suggest you make a *big* pot of coffee and read Bart de Smet's blog post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/20/reactive-extensions-v2-0-release-candidate-available-now.aspx

In short, you aren't actually creating Timer objects when you use Observable.Interval, what actually happens *is* efficient - however, the precise behaviour is quite involved and well worth understanding.

EDIT: I've done some detailed analysis on this following a counter-claim on the Rx Forums. See here for a fuller discussion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/13227561-deaa-4984-a52e-601b8a9f8e14

Short version - you get new Timers when the due time is < 10 seconds away, otherwise a single Timer is leveraged.

Comment: Marking your comment as the answer since it provides a more in-depth link!  Thanks James

Answer (score 2):

I asked the question on the Reactive forums - it sounds like it is 100% ok to do this.  [This is the answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/13227561-deaa-4984-a52e-601b8a9f8e14)

To quote it here, the answer was:

> From memory there is a single thread that processes the timings and there is a single priority heap that keeps track of all the scheduled observables. It scales incredibly well. So even with tens of thousands of `Observable.Interval` queries you only have one actual timer and one actual thread managing it all.

Comment: See the blog post referenced in my answer for a lot more on this. The behaviour changes *a lot* between Rx versions.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't. Better add to a list with expiration timestamp and use f.e. a thread to process the list.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing that you would notice is that the number of timer events that can be handled at the same time is limited by the number of CPU cores. If too many events would be triggered at the same time, they would be queued and potentially handled with a considerable delay.

Also, if too many threads are started at the same time, you will get a lot of overhead by the context switching, so the handlers would run slowly, both from the overhead and the fact that so many threads need to divide up the CPU time.

Consider if you can have a single timer running, and let it handle a list of logical timers.